# How do I show content of hidden password boxes?

Tags: snow-leopard, password, ftp

About 1 year ago, I set up FTP access on a webserver that's being used for our client. The project temporarily stopped and is just resuming now. I need to set up the same FTP access on another computer. I already forgot the password we used for it before and I can't seem to locate the email detailing the server info. Our server admin is currently unreachable so I have to come up with a solution myself.

I am looking for a tool similar to [this one](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bullets_password_view.html), but for OS X 10.6.8.

If it helps any, the FTP client I used is Transmit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just solved my question. As it turns out, the password is stored in the Keychain Access. I just searched for the server and ticked the "Show password" checkbox on that particular item. Problem solved!